# ios app crash at launch when import xml

Tags: ios

My app's crash at launch when I try to import a xml file only when it is not already openned. If the app is openned, the xml file is imported correctly.
Suddenly I cannot use Xcode to see what happenned.

Is there a way to see more logs than the crash log ? Or may be someone could help me with this...

```
Date/Time:           2016-09-14 10:56:02.02 +0200
Launch Time:         2016-09-14 10:56:02.02 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001003de6d8
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001003de6d8 0x1002a0000 + 1304280
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001003de6d8 0x1002a0000 + 1304280
2   xia                             0x000000010014e0f8 0x1000a0000 + 712952
3   xia                             0x000000010015112c 0x1000a0000 + 725292
4   xia                             0x0000000100153530 0x1000a0000 + 734512
5   UIKit                           0x00000001863659ec __45-[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:]_block_invoke + 796
6   UIKit                           0x00000001863654f0 -[UIApplication _applicationOpenURL:payload:] + 628
7   UIKit                           0x000000018635a4bc -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3728
8   UIKit                           0x000000018635e5f0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
9   UIKit                           0x000000018635b764 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001828fb7ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001828fb618 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 168
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001828fb9c8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180f1109c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180f10b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180f0e830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180e38c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
17  UIKit                           0x000000018612394c -[UIApplication _run] + 460
18  UIKit                           0x000000018611e088 UIApplicationMain + 204
19  xia                             0x00000001001568b0 0x1000a0000 + 747696
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001809d68b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180af54d8 kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001809b87d8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001809a7648 _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180af4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180af4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180af4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180af4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180af4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180bbd020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000100b99400   x1: 0x0000000180bb68f4   x2: 0x000000014e568420   x3: 0x0000000000000004
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000100b99408   x9: 0x0000000000001000  x10: 0x000000014e56c000  x11: 0x0000000000000fff
   x12: 0x000000014e568000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0xffffffffffffc000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000180b20168  x17: 0x00000001004bc040  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000000000002  x21: 0x0000000000000039  x22: 0x000000010018eb70  x23: 0x0000000000000002
   x24: 0x000000000000000b  x25: 0x000000010018f06a  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x000000014e52c090
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fd5d340   lr: 0x00000001003de6d8
    sp: 0x000000016fd5d300   pc: 0x00000001003de6d8 cpsr: 0x20000000

Binary Images:
0x1000a0000 - 0x10019bfff xia arm64  <685b9025a86338d084e66b085b18c1d3> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/xia
0x1002a0000 - 0x1004bbfff libswiftCore.dylib arm64  <17ea2138fbe232759f642dea8a84befe> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
0x10073c000 - 0x10074bfff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64  <1426b26ab021337f908cbf9a86c482f0> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
0x100768000 - 0x10076ffff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64  <2566bcc80e993f5bb86b22a1b15803de> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
0x100788000 - 0x10078ffff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64  <84be54efa8ef3fd0a6b574c5b931ad87> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
0x1007a0000 - 0x1007bbfff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64  <6876f03e334c300c8ee3126bcb312219> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
0x100808000 - 0x1008c7fff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64  <b4c6e01c18983b9792c9bf772fb9ad5c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
0x1009d8000 - 0x1009dffff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64  <84eb3700259d3cf799b05c9935373084> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
0x1009fc000 - 0x100a27fff libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib arm64  <ad6fec67a1523898a58af0a11fbba11b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
0x100b04000 - 0x100b0ffff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64  <ce29993d6ef234ca9a45b2b1c3fe0895> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
0x100b28000 - 0x100b2ffff libswiftCoreMedia.dylib arm64  <c928777b596d36a79541fd46c4c7c72c> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib
0x100b48000 - 0x100b53fff libswiftCoreAudio.dylib arm64  <48e7fdc0f9d23e31b3aa81c8e70e1e67> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
0x100b80000 - 0x100b87fff libswiftos.dylib arm64  <b237a2add8293f798f6fb6cf64c3a462> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/759A7901-CAFF-4BA3-8C1D-D854F6D0CFA0/xia.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
0x120084000 - 0x1200b3fff dyld arm64  <a1862e29910f3f069a363730df77dad7> /usr/lib/dyld
0x180540000 - 0x180541fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <5bb501a091dc3a22a5544d34a4312de1> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x180544000 - 0x180596fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <9ec0d9dcf728349582c26a7da72f0364> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x180598000 - 0x1805b7fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <aaa40b7f52513cf79c6f814b133556a7> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1805b8000 - 0x180924fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <939f392022903f2da2858e676e4191ef> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x180928000 - 0x18092cfff libcache.dylib arm64  <43424f4c7252330ca92c1a865da896e1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x180930000 - 0x18093bfff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <e47d758d207e32c8ab546b59785d2ab8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x18093c000 - 0x18093ffff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <b77c451c7ffb356fb3c8368cac95d8f3> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x180940000 - 0x180947fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <1c1678aa36073b42b4406c6dbb06e9f0> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x180948000 - 0x1809a3fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <b42ff635d1303d45bafe057e5a1e6243> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1809a4000 - 0x1809d2fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <65568801b7463adeb6e20dc25d14d801> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1809d4000 - 0x1809d6fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <89518667b02d3d1680929e246eb35939> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1809d8000 - 0x1809d8fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <fbb5f1442c3039188da689963efde4d8> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1809dc000 - 0x1809e0fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <1f37b179ad26307192b3b763ba5f816a> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1809e4000 - 0x1809e5fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <267c6cbaf2193309bd8a191fad38cc79> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1809e8000 - 0x1809fefff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <fffe50d37b1c3f92af6f4a68a6d60068> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x180a00000 - 0x180a01fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <8bbf799e57f93ed1be24cf2ce6c221a3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x180a04000 - 0x180a83fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <c3408ef0608b3d68acc24d59d6af9528> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x180a84000 - 0x180a87fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <c5ce1ced5659354ab63871b42d04a7cd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x180a88000 - 0x180a8bfff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <504648cfa43d3668b9678b74e33697f2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x180a8c000 - 0x180a8dfff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <8f94549c633036aa99efb0f067031a05> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x180a90000 - 0x180aa6fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <498e424eb31f3d5cb49523cec07f339d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x180aa8000 - 0x180ab0fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <573c3639fde83e87885bfe02c057538d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x180ab4000 - 0x180ad6fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <932df5ba705a3b6d948c5dcff196ea6b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x180ad8000 - 0x180af9fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <fd5f89b7e48c3bc3b3464805d726450d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x180afc000 - 0x180b18fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <a97bf91d4a233dbc94bef06734a2eac0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x180b1c000 - 0x180b35fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <a8af95191b283ca9aa7f9cf80c459bf5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x180b38000 - 0x180b9bfff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <a8e4200aecc73e56a8458a0e9cb4a6f0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x180b9c000 - 0x180ba5fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <d1a7579c71943631845c2908d69bfbc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x180ba8000 - 0x180bb2fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <da8d7d155da230d287a67c46e9b3ccbc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x180bb4000 - 0x180bb9fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <4386956061113d7a9e415e543b1243bc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x180bbc000 - 0x180bc4fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <8e409f0b333f3749b544b337154247b2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x180bc8000 - 0x180bcafff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <b673378c7a6236c69b3b35f3b6520807> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x180bcc000 - 0x180bdcfff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <7de1ebaaeb5f3a5893337941c4c25d8f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x180be0000 - 0x180be5fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <b0067e5ea3ca3b28abc5cb7d50390363> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x180be8000 - 0x180be8fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <630bf4c89edf3935b7afe56abdb5caad> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x180bec000 - 0x180c11fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <fc63a0a505523f7fac2c4ea9d9662ba1> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x180c14000 - 0x180e19fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <d1856fdadee0393ebd636fa4020a454b> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x180e1c000 - 0x180e2dfff libz.1.dylib arm64  <8fcb56adfdc13e9593582266b1e4ac18> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x180e30000 - 0x1811b0fff CoreFoundation arm64  <182fd72b7fdf330b8dbf70db93af6b63> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1811b4000 - 0x1811c4fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <d045301bcacc37d785d754d5c978d979> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x1811c8000 - 0x1811c8fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <c4ee08bffdfc3ce0990c1fbeb858f9dc> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x1811cc000 - 0x18123dfff IOKit arm64  <81620a37c2073ceeb9f474604f2c828b> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x181240000 - 0x181260fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <9cc485a12c323768a6b6e88d973bd44e> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x181264000 - 0x18134efff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <d6c7d4fa4ab033ea94a89058ae09b14b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x181350000 - 0x1813c2fff Security arm64  <4c7468d385513e4db673ec80c318ee20> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1813c4000 - 0x18141dfff SystemConfiguration arm64  <92717250c7393c44878d137773604d46> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x181420000 - 0x181508fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <c703a175f1c43ed28d81b839ba961183> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x18150c000 - 0x1817a0fff CFNetwork arm64  <e65cd15333e435b5975900dc9111f58b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1817a4000 - 0x1817b1fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <8ebfd413e3fd3889b546857fcf554b6f> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x1817b4000 - 0x1817cdfff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <68bb861dc8bd3547b5ace073ed504b14> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x1817d0000 - 0x1817eafff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <1a2c1f709f213faf81fd2223b719c899> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1817ec000 - 0x181816fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <bf6ae1a9c965363ba9f10ff0ca32ee7c> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x181818000 - 0x181836fff libextension.dylib arm64  <8a88fb35fee03a36ae138e676b9a0e9f> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x181838000 - 0x181839fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <cdb184e30c3c303694a96b3150520673> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x18183c000 - 0x181aaafff Foundation arm64  <7cf4edf781cb30438b812ded8716cd95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x181aac000 - 0x181b57fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <097b7e769a3439ad8fdb3abb0edc9daf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x181b58000 - 0x181ebdfff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <566419f65c9338599694a04da8e20fbf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x181ec0000 - 0x182125fff vImage arm64  <789df1b35e183397803583a25feff3c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x182128000 - 0x18214afff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <3c655ae6f62035bbba069387c490efbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x18214c000 - 0x18215ffff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <94d099e954d638e39ef1773639ef61af> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x182160000 - 0x18216ffff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <80ca4fb770613c76b2449daf05c6dc25> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x182170000 - 0x1821dcfff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <f4e8d68f55af3511a28a616737dcc354> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1821e0000 - 0x1821e0fff vecLib arm64  <546ad53c3a4a36709fdf6e50b76b2ec9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1821e4000 - 0x1821e4fff Accelerate arm64  <a1953e95570a3de6a923a812ffbd90ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x1821e8000 - 0x182713fff CoreGraphics arm64  <f58e942f6bd039dc8de98619e53500bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x182714000 - 0x182728fff GraphicsServices arm64  <d8509ae0233539218bf97db29a7d31c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x18272c000 - 0x182774fff AppSupport arm64  <1469530c1aa03d2486d678bed8482764> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x182778000 - 0x18284bfff MobileCoreServices arm64  <2096d560a53b3fd28ff0a7f46e3ba060> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18284c000 - 0x18289bfff BaseBoard arm64  <b6f2014b564430538f5252776acfa530> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18289c000 - 0x1828a7fff AssertionServices arm64  <48c978bd14553765b4a7f1cee1b14c83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x1828a8000 - 0x1828ccfff BackBoardServices arm64  <207836d8c1833eeab468f622f4d0f366> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x1828d0000 - 0x1828d3fff MobileSystemServices arm64  <6d85ae92680935bbb51db96c7a021118> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x1828d4000 - 0x182909fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <b1a46eb324d23a51813b565ae7f04b88> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x18290c000 - 0x182916fff UserNotificationServices arm64  <74d3e76dff833048b39ae8e0ceb44140> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserNotificationServices.framework/UserNotificationServices
0x182918000 - 0x182944fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <6535787e172939d0b8abfe852a185b3d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x182948000 - 0x182959fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <169edc8949693d349807056d1e316f2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x18295c000 - 0x182962fff IOSurface arm64  <d62fd4ed209e32f98d5dbc34f9484ef4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x182964000 - 0x182970fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <36e1e9187c193410a5f7cf46e3dc7afe> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x182974000 - 0x182986fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <3b4a2b63b2a9334fa8019a4152d3aa49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x182988000 - 0x18298afff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <65789d64b5f937e987c6f27125a38100> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x18298c000 - 0x1829cdfff AppleJPEG arm64  <8b25b915b426335f8d9112a8c7e29e46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x1829d0000 - 0x182cf3fff ImageIO arm64  <985b712758c43d62a2104d9e708fb2e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x182cf4000 - 0x182cf8fff TCC arm64  <09fcccda721f35c3936e68acf3d216a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x182cfc000 - 0x182d01fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <51bcd4b61f3739eb85fdcc4a037e3696> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x182d04000 - 0x182d11fff PowerLog arm64  <a50ba8508d733823be55425db249606c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x182d8c000 - 0x182da3fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <ac77f3a3cad832a7b748c30e013bbc0b> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x182ff0000 - 0x182ff4fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <69b5ba7317d532b898c3ffb5574bb883> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x182ff8000 - 0x182ffcfff IOAccelerator arm64  <8763c48f6ea73eae887a414462ffe098> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x183000000 - 0x183001fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <ed32d5e2c1e630b18097aa7890c92171> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x183004000 - 0x183007fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <abe2067778503127a31c42352d2e43ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x183008000 - 0x18304efff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <e67acd0811bf318dadb48a49b97bee7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x183050000 - 0x18305afff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <fdc295986ea03203bbfc904ffc4cca6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x18305c000 - 0x183063fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <8917a7dda29e33f2bfa43d5f4d0bb114> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x183064000 - 0x183064fff libmetal_timestamp.dylib arm64  <bdc8f33a1b453c8f827726c7f46640dc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
0x183068000 - 0x1830aefff Metal arm64  <95ce1f8a4d483d11aa49533e2ae2a568> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x1830b0000 - 0x1830bafff OpenGLES arm64  <7c7a0c5191f53f518e994638139ca1df> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x1830bc000 - 0x1830defff CoreVideo arm64  <31ef8b764af3301ea5e7267fcae838cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x18311c000 - 0x18320efff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <1c378c57054a32a6b2eed4e3cbb3a2b7> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x183210000 - 0x1832c9fff CoreAudio arm64  <25687ef4b3c4389f828006882b280db4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1832cc000 - 0x1832cffff UserFS arm64  <693602c29c64370aab1a77544ddc7e5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x1832d0000 - 0x1833befff CoreMedia arm64  <e4b8c027690c3a268d47209f071ea0b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x183440000 - 0x183520fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <7ab9c32919d731969bc2a75b3f03aa17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x183524000 - 0x1835a6fff VideoToolbox arm64  <08992b8332af3196aa17a31365296e9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x1835a8000 - 0x1835a8fff FontServices arm64  <39a3005cf101328f94f3a412cfa04fae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x1835ac000 - 0x1836cffff CoreText arm64  <688f036ee040335aaf44f555b7b98ace> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x183714000 - 0x183a2dfff AudioToolbox arm64  <3acc644e69ff3aedae6e3af12f13c58c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x183a30000 - 0x183bdefff QuartzCore arm64  <cbbd0fe690bc3efbb32085b9cdbc292f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x183be8000 - 0x183bf9fff libcmph.dylib arm64  <f9b0e4b1c2b83f848b351670183dcf24> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x183c1c000 - 0x183c9cfff LanguageModeling arm64  <25b1d85465f531118bbcd9b3afcb4151> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x183d80000 - 0x183d97fff libmarisa.dylib arm64  <72aff9de7b7a3d0f8d24b2f2e33599b1> /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib
0x183d98000 - 0x183e5ffff ProofReader arm64  <e62d51dcf4a134a2981acc214a79ee83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x183e60000 - 0x183e66fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <dbc84b51887d3c239f748993bfe87be2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x183e68000 - 0x183e77fff MobileAsset arm64  <4f36adf36909306e8cdda53f431aec5e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x183e78000 - 0x183ed9fff ColorSync arm64  <7a7f1de762e734a1b0185bbcf4c5805d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x183edc000 - 0x183f27fff MetalPerformanceShaders arm64  <7530c46bdba43048b3780b308d1e0349> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x183f28000 - 0x184354fff FaceCore arm64  <9fe0da65d44f3e58872fa11c1d79a801> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x184358000 - 0x1843d3fff Quagga arm64  <872de61a4b163a57b1e5df76124b9013> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x1843d4000 - 0x18457efff CoreImage arm64  <df4ffff30c383def8d08b5b28b6df84d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x184580000 - 0x1845b2fff TextInput arm64  <475a479564123e0aafd3f578a8ad861a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x1845b4000 - 0x1845c1fff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <767e55a612343e498e13731d796f2f9f> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x1845d0000 - 0x184bb5fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <bbe4011181dc32b78bcde421ea8f5ded> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x184dac000 - 0x185d84fff WebCore arm64  <c34b05e2e0153569b040074396aa9cd4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x185d88000 - 0x185db1fff libxslt.1.dylib arm64  <6553a930d8933aa0b054d0ebd966c83a> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x185db4000 - 0x185e8ffff WebKitLegacy arm64  <6bf2496789113045a9c472f536802b90> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x185e90000 - 0x185f48fff CoreUI arm64  <1fd04759197f312ab80538caca1dd94e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x185f4c000 - 0x185f71fff DictionaryServices arm64  <03b326076ce4388099fb7442bcbcbd3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x185f74000 - 0x185f74fff HangTracer arm64  <2989b93ed68939929f8898e8d586bdc2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HangTracer.framework/HangTracer
0x185f78000 - 0x185fc6fff PhysicsKit arm64  <d5863be3b3d3375997ce983229cfa34a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x185fc8000 - 0x18609efff UIFoundation arm64  <a012ee13e0bf395794c95ce1b5670728> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x1860a0000 - 0x186ccafff UIKit arm64  <bc9398e03d593b3fb4b66794602f9602> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x187d10000 - 0x187d15fff ConstantClasses arm64  <e397ebe2ca23360688f15acf8b0a3e6c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x188924000 - 0x188935fff UserManagement arm64  <1d49514ccc853a8f8ad3fdec01ad4766> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserManagement.framework/UserManagement
0x18fdb4000 - 0x18fe0dfff CoreBrightness arm64  <d3db17f73b17334193450eb8569238f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreBrightness.framework/CoreBrightness
0x1929c0000 - 0x1929d2fff libCGInterfaces.dylib arm64  <c4505720159f37a7ac9aa8fc453a5cdb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Libraries/libCGInterfaces.dylib
0x194908000 - 0x194913fff libGSFontCache.dylib arm64  <af7bcf4952573e29a1a9ab26dc13b2cf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libGSFontCache.dylib
```

EDIT : here is how the import is done in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    let url = url.standardized
    var errorAtImageImport = true
    var errorAtXMLImport = true
    let errorAtSVGImport = true
    let now:Int = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

    // read file to extract image
    var path = url.path
    path = path.replacingOccurrences(of: "/private", with: "")
    let xml = getXML(path, check: false)
    let ext = path.substring(with: path.characters.index(path.endIndex, offsetBy: -3)..<path.characters.index(path.endIndex, offsetBy: 0))
    switch (ext) {
        case "xml": // no other case for now
```

Comment: I guess importing is doing on com.apple.main-thread, I guess you should use some background thread for importing xml.

Comment: I've edited to explain where the import is done.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by moving the method for import in an another class.
Thanks to Sanoj for the clue ;-)